# Transfere from Coinbase to Ethereum wallet did not show up?

Tags: wallets, coinbase

I recently transfered my Ether from coinbase to Mist (ethereum wallet) 
i used the ethereum wallet address and sent to that from my coinbase account.
coinbase says that the task is complete and has removed all my ether from the account, however it has not shwn up in my ether wallet?
iv signed up to eterscan to check if there is a transaction pending but it also shows 0.00 ether in my posession.

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the transaction here with your mist wallet address as well. Thanks.

Comment: the amount has shown up in etherscan but still has not shown up in my ethereum wallet. should it take more than a day?

Comment: No! Usually you'll be included in the next 2-3 blocks, which on average is 14.16 seconds according to https://ethstats.net/ atm. Could you link me the transaction ID + your wallet address? Sometimes Coinbase is really slow (with everything), and I'm not really sure how their wallet functions! Right now I wouldn't be too panicked so long as you correctly entered the wallet address. Also, Coinbase throws an error if the entered address is invalid, so you're almost certainly fine.

Comment: Hi there. If you're Mist wallet isn't completely synced with the blockchain, then the funds won't show up. However, if your funds also aren't showing up on Etherscan, then the first thing to do would be to check the addresses match.

Comment: Mine is also not in there. Super weird. I have 1.5 ETH on Coinbase and it shows that my balance is 0 on etherscan.io . This looks sketchy...